# Returning a lower case ASCII string from a (possibly encoded) string fetched using urllib2 or BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, utf-8

I am fetching data from a web page using urllib2. The content of all the pages is in the English language so there is no issue of dealing with non-English text. The pages are encoded however, and they sometimes contain HTML entities such as £ or the copyright symbol etc.

I want to check if portions of a page contains certain keywords - however, I want to do a case insensitive check (for obvious reasons).

What is the best way to convert the returned page content into all lower case letters?

```
def get_page_content_as_lower_case(url):
    request = urllib2.Request(url)
    page = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    temp = page.read()

    return str(temp).lower() # this dosen't work because page contains utf-8 data
```

**[[Update]]**

I don't have to use urllib2 to get the data, in fact I may use BeautifulSoup instead, since I need to retrieve data from a specific element(s) in the page - for which BS is a much better choice. I have changed the title to reflect this.

HOWEVER, the problem still remains that the fetched data is in some non-asci coding (supposed to be) in utf-8. I did check one of the pages and the encoding was iso-8859-1.

Since I am only concerned with the English language, I want to know how I can obtain a lower case ASCII string version of the data retrieved from the page - so that I can carry out a case sensitive test as to whether a keyword is found in the text.

I am assuming that the fact that I have restricted myself to only English (from English speaking websites) reduces the choices of encoding?. I don't know much about encoding, but I assuming that the valid choices are:

- ASCII
- iso-8859-1
- utf-8

Is that a valid assumption, and if yes, perhaps there is a way to write a 'robust' function that accepts an encoded string containing English text and returns a lower case ASCII string version of it?

Comment: Your question has a wrong assumption: that you can compare Unicode by mapping things to lowercase and comparing them. You cannot.  You must map them to foldcase.  Otherwise it won’t work.  Consider *Σίσυφος*, which has three sigmas in it: one uppercase and two that are lowercase. Mapping to lowercase still leaves you with sigmas that won’t binary-compare equal. You must use foldcase.

Comment: @Homunculus Reticulli Your update completely changes the scope of the question (and instead of assuming UTF-8, you should really look at the HTTP headers and the beginning of the HTML file). Please ask a new question for that.

Comment: [there is no such thing as plain text](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html). You need to know character encoding of your text. [`BeautifulSoup` does the conversion to Unicode for you](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Beautiful%20Soup%20Gives%20You%20Unicode,%20Dammit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BeautifulSoup stores data as Unicode internally so you don't need to perform character encoding manipulations manually.

To find keywords (case-insensitive) in a text (*not* in attribute values, or tag names):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import urllib2
from contextlib import closing 

import regex # pip install regex
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

with closing(urllib2.urlopen(URL)) as page:
     soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
     print soup(text=regex.compile(ur'(?fi)\L<keywords>',
                                   keywords=['your', 'keywords', 'go', 'here']))
```

#### Example (Unicode words by @tchrist)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import regex
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, Comment

html = u'''<div attr="PoSt in attribute should not be found">
<!-- it must not find post inside a comment either -->
<ol> <li> tag names must not match
<li> Post will be found
<li> the same with post
<li> and poﬆ
<li> and poﬅ
<li> this is ignored
</ol>
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# remove comments
comments = soup.findAll(text=lambda t: isinstance(t, Comment))
for comment in comments: comment.extract()

# find text with keywords (case-insensitive)
print ''.join(soup(text=regex.compile(ur'(?fi)\L<opts>', opts=['post', 'li'])))
# compare it with '.lower()'
print '.lower():'
print ''.join(soup(text=lambda t: any(k in t.lower() for k in ['post', 'li'])))
# or exact match
print 'exact match:'
print ''.join(soup(text=' the same with post\n'))
```

#### Output

```
 Post will be found
 the same with post
 and poﬆ
 and poﬅ

.lower():
 Post will be found
 the same with post

exact match:
 the same with post
```

Answer (score 3):

Case-insensitive string search is more complicated than simply searching in the lower-cased variant. For example, a German user would expect to match both `STRASSE` as well as `Straße` with the search term `Straße`, but `'STRASSE'.lower() == 'strasse'` (and you can't simply replace a double s with ß - there's no ß in [Trasse](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Trasse)). Other languages (in particular [Turkish](http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/turkish-i18n.html)) will have similar complications as well.

If you're looking to support other languages than English, you should therefore use a library that can handle proper casefolding (such as [Matthew Barnett's `regexp`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex)).

That being said, the way to extract the page's content is:

```
import contextlib
def get_page_content(url):
  with contextlib.closing(urllib2.urlopen(url)) as uh:
    content = uh.read().decode('utf-8')
  return content
  # You can call .lower() on the result, but that won't work in general
```

Comment: And the solution to different capitalization in different languages is to set the proper locale - using Python's locale module, before calling the conversion in unicode objects. The locale should be set to the language the html contents are in.

Comment: `urllib2.urlopen()` object is not a context manager. You could use `contextlib.closing()` to combine `with`-statement and `urllib2.urlopen()`.

Comment: @jsbueno No, that does not suffice, as the `STRASSE` example shows. The problem lies in assuming that `x.lower() == y.lower()` is the correct way to compare case-insenitively. Also, the **locale module does not affect UTF-8 decoding** (I think that's what you mean with `calling the conversion in unicode objects`). No offense, but that's just utter bs.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian My mistake, I tried it with Python 3.x's urllib, and didn't notice that they added context manager functionality in between.

Comment: Um, no. Case in Unicode is not a locale-specific thing, with the exception of the Turkic İ issue. The correct thing to do is to use the Unicode casefolding tables. Python’s normal *re* module doesn’t understand this, but Matthew Barnett’s replacement for the same certainly does so. It even understands full Unicode casefolding, not just simple. It is ***ALWAYS WRONG*** to compare `x.lower() == y.lower()` for Unicode. You must use Unicode’s foldcase; it’s its whole *raison d’être*.

Comment: @phihag: I'm using Python 2.6, so I was unable to use the with Syntax. However even still, after ammending the code, I get the following error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 21931: unexpected code byte. Incidentally, I do not need to worry about handling non English text.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli Sorry, I don't follow. [Python 2.6 supports](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) the `with` statement just fine. In **2.5**, you'd have to add `from __future__ import with_statement` to the beginning of your code. Your error does indicate that the encoding isn't UTF-8 after all. Can you post an example URL where the problem occurs? I can't reproduce it with http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=uYLX3SVL .

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli Unicode guarantees that the English word variously spelled *POST*, *Post*, *post*, *poſt*, *poﬆ*, and *poﬅ* (`POST, Post, post, po\x{17F}t, po\x{FB06}, po\x{FB05}`) are all the same foldcase as each other.
This is just another illustration of why you must use the Unicode casefolding tables.

Comment: @phihag The −1 was indeed from me, but it was a dumb klutz move. I meant to hit +1. I’m not kidding, either. Now that you’ve editted, I’ve been able to fix my vote. Thanks.

Comment: @tchrist: [`regex`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) does work: https://gist.github.com/1680518

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Yes, it certainly does. I’m a big fan of mrab’s work.

Answer (score 2):

Or with [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html):

```
page_text = requests.get(url).text
lowercase_text = page_text.lower()
```

(Requests will automatically decode the response.)

As @tchrist says, `.lower()` will not do the job for unicode text.

You could check out this alternative regex implementation which implements case folding for unicode case insensitive comparison: http://code.google.com/p/mrab-regex-hg/

There are also casefolding tables available: http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/CaseFolding.txt

Comment: Mapping to lowercase is the wrong thing to do. You must map to foldcase.