# BeautifulSoupTag, strings and UnicodeEncodeError is not so beautiful

Tags: python, utf-8, ascii, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have spent several frustrating hours this morning, trying to handle strings from scraped web pages. I can't seem to get a consistent way of lowercasing the extracted string so I can check for keywords - and its driving me round the bend.

Here is a snippet of code that retrieves text from a DOM element:

```
temp = i.find('div', 'foobar').find('div')
if temp is not None and temp.contents is not None:
    temp2 = whitespace.sub(' ', temp.contents[0])
    content = str(temp2)
```

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in
>   position 150: ordinal not in range(128)

I also tried the following statements - NONE of which  worked; i.e. they resulted in the same error being thrown:

```
content = (str(temp2)).decode('utf-8').lower()
content = str(temp2.decode('utf-8')).lower()
```

Does anyone know how to convert teh text contained within a BeautifulSoupTag into lowercase ASCII, so I may conduct a case insensitive search for keyword(s)?

Comment: Try to find the answer here: [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Beautiful Soup Gives You Unicode, Dammit)

Comment: Can you just use `unicode(temp2)`?

Comment: read my answer that you've accepted to [yours almost the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9012607/4279)

Answer (score 2):

You may want ASCII, but you need Unicode, and it's a good chance that you've got it already. XML parsers return `unicode` objects.

Firstly do `print type(temp2)` ... It should be `unicode` unless something unfortunate has happened, like maybe that `whitespace.sub()` thingy; what is that?

If you want to normalise multiple whitespace characters into a single space, do

`temp2 = u' '.join(temp.contents[0].split())`

That will make that nasty u'\xA0' vanish, becase it's a whitespace (NO-BREAK SPACE).

Then try `content = temp2.lower()`