# converting NavigableString to unicode string

Tags: python, string, unicode, beautifulsoup

When I run the following code:

`if substr in movie.lowercase:`

I get the following error

`AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'lowercase'`

`movie` is from here:

`movie = row.td.div.h4.string`

I tried to change it to (without success)

`movie = row.td.div.h4.string.string`

or

`movie = unicode(row.td.div.h4.string)`

Do you know how to convert NavigableString to normal unicode string with `lowercase` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`unicode()` doesn't have `.lowercase()` method it has `.lower()`.

`NavigableString` is an instance of `unicode`. It has all `unicode` methods.

[A case-insensitive search is more complicated then just calling `.lower()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9012607/4279) e.g. [full unicode casefolding in Python (case-insensitive search for keywords)](https://gist.github.com/1680518).

Comment: This answer does not explicitly respond to the question. The question asks how to convert a NavigableString into a string. While your answer is a more elegant solution, it doesn't answer the question. Could you please update your answer with an explanation of how one would convert NavigableString to a string if such a thing is possible?

Comment: @melchoir55 the answer explicitly says that NavigableString *is* an instance of `unicode`. If you don't understand that it means that NavigableString *is* a string already; ask.

Answer (score 0):

There should not be any problem just using python's str() method on the navigable string object you have. From my experience with NavigableString's they are already in unicode so if you want a string on which .lower will work then you need to cast it to a python string (UTF-8) then recast it back to unicode.