# python: TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly

Tags: python, search, typeerror

I am getting the following error with Python 3.1.4 which used to work well in Python 2.7.2.

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly. I get the error on the if statement. Please let me know how to fix this. Thanks!
```

In

```
for word in keywords: # Iterate through keywords
    if re.search(r"\b"+word+r"\b",line1):           #Search kewords in the input line
```

Update1:

I am trying to create a list from keywords which is in a file. Each line has one keyword. Am I reading the file properly?

```
keyword_file=r"KEYWORDS.txt"
f0=open(keyword_file,'r')
keywords = map(lambda a: a.split('\n'),map(str.lower, f0.readlines()))
```

keyword file contains:

```
Keyword1
Keyword2
.
.
.
Keywordn
```

I want a list called `keywords = ['Keyword1','Keyword2',...,'Keywordn']`

Comment: either `word` or `line1` seems to be list instead of a string, like you expect. Which of those it is I can't tell, you'd have to provide more code.

Comment: What is the list here? line1? re.search() takes the pattern and the string to search in, not a list.

Comment: @NiklasB. You are correct. Word is a list. Please see my edit question for more information. I am having trouble importing the list in the right format.

Comment: @Pradeep: I don't see any update..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You split the lines although they have already been split by `readlines()`. This should work:

```
# actually no need for readline() here, the file object can be
# directly used to iterate over the lines
keywords = (line.strip().lower() for line in f0)
# ...
for word in keywords:
  if re.search(r"\b"+word+r"\b",line1):
```

What's used here is a generator expression. You should learn about those, they are quite handy, as well as about [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) which can often be used to replace `map` and `filter`.

Note that it might be more performant to create the regular expression before the loop, like this:

```
keywords = (line.strip() for line in f0)
# use re.escape here in case the keyword contains a special regex character
regex = r'\b({0})\b'.format('|'.join(map(re.escape, keywords)))
# pre-compile the regex (build up the state machine)
regex = re.compile(regex, re.IGNORECASE)

# inside the loop over the lines
if regex.search(line1)
  print "ok"
```

Comment: Thanks Niklas. the keywords list is not in the expect format. I am unable to view it because it is a generator object. Can it be made to look like keywords = ['Keyword1','Keyword2',...,'Keywordn']

Comment: yes, by using a list comprehension instead: `keywords = [x.strip().lower() for x in f0.readlines()]`

Comment: drop `.readlines()`. You don't need to create a list of lines here.

Comment: If `keywords` may overlap then the longer keywords should go before the shorter one (if you'd like to extract the match).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: You are right about the first suggestion, I edited this (must have missed it when copying the original code). I don't quite get your second point, though: Why should longer keywords be preferred? We use `\b` to match the word boundary as well.

Comment: `.lower()` doesn't work for Unicode strings e.g., [`regex.match('(?fi)straße', 'STRASSE')`](http://ideone.com/X0Npj) finds the match ([`regex` module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex)), but `.lower()` doesn't; another [example](https://gist.github.com/1680518). See [discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9012665/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Good to know. Although I am not sure whether this is actually desired, so it's up to the OP to decide.

Comment: if there are no non-word characters inside a keyword then you don't need to put the longer words first and `map(re.escape, keywords)` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

It means that your keyword object contains lists.

```
# this is valid:
import re
keywords=["a","b","c"]

for word in keywords: # Iterate through keywords
    if re.search(r"\b"+word+r"\b",line1):
        print "ok"

# this is not valid. This is the kind of error you get:    
keywords=[["a","b"],"c"]

for word in keywords: # Iterate through keywords
    if re.search(r"\b"+word+r"\b",line1):
        print "ok"
```

You should print `word` to make sure you understand what it is. It's possible but not likely that you would like to use `"".join(word)` instead of `word` in your regular expression.